# Comments to my reddit clone ruby pulls a NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I'm trying to add comment functionality of my Reddit clone. This is the comments controller that creates a comments and adds it to a post.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @comment = Comment.new
        #authorize @comment       # from include Pundit in the application controller, authorize is an inherited method
   end

    def create
         @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
    end

 private

    def comment_params
       params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
    end
 end
```

I'm trying to add a comments field for every post page by using a form partial that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for [topic, post] do |f| %>

<%= form_group_tag(comment[:text]) do %>
    <%= f.label :text %>
    <%= f.text_area :text, rows: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your comment" %>
    <% end %>

<div class = "form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

This form partial should appear at the post.show.html.erb so I put it there

```
  <h1><%= markdown @post.title %></h1>

<div class="row"> <!-- what others are there besides row? -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p><%= markdown @post.body %></p>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
        <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, text: @post.comments.new } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I'm getting a NameError for my 'comment' on the form_group_tag line. Most of what I defined here comes from my code for adding new posts, which seemed to work. Is there something missing here?

---

I fixed my name error by adding comments to the form_for line, but I'm getting NoMethodError for my topic,post,comment path, so I thought it'd be helpful to add what rake routes is pulling up.

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                   devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                  devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)              devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)             devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                  devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                    devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                   devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                      devise/registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                           devise/registrations#destroy
   user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)              devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)          devise/confirmations#new
                     GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)              devise/confirmations#show
                user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                       users#update
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                       users#update
         topic_posts POST   /topics/:topic_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
      new_topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
     edit_topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
          topic_post GET    /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                     PATCH  /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                     PUT    /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                     DELETE /topics/:topic_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
              topics GET    /topics(.:format)                          topics#index
                     POST   /topics(.:format)                          topics#create
           new_topic GET    /topics/new(.:format)                      topics#new
          edit_topic GET    /topics/:id/edit(.:format)                 topics#edit
               topic GET    /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#show
                     PATCH  /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#update
                     PUT    /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#update
                     DELETE /topics/:id(.:format)                      topics#destroy
       post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)         comments#create
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)                           posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)                           posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                       posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                  posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                       posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                       posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                       posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                       posts#destroy
               about GET    /about(.:format)                           welcome#about
                root GET    /                                          welcome#index
```

BTW: how does this routes.rb file look?

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
     devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update]
     resources :topics do
        resources :posts, except: [:index]
     end
  resources :posts do
     resources :comments, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @post.comments.new } %>
...

<%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :text %>
  <%= f.text_area :text, rows: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter your comment" %>

  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>

<% end %>
...
```

If it does not help, try to temporary comment form_group_tag and send error here

Comment: I'm getting a undefined method `topic_post_comments_path' both when I comment and when I don't.

Comment: I edited my question to include my `rake routes` and my routes.rb

Comment: I edited my answer - try <%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %>

Comment: :text is pulling a NoMethodError too. Could be something wrong with the Comments Controller

Comment: Try form_for version from edited answer (without form_group_tag). If you have the same error, show your schema.db for comments. (may be you have not text field?) If you have this field try to rename it to body or smth else (text is a system word) and try again

Comment: It's called body in the schema, so I should be calling it `:body`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're sending the `comment` down to the partial as `text`.

```
... locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, text: @post.comments.new } %>
                                          ^^^^
```

And by the way you're not saving the comment in the create action.

Comment: Ok cool, I thought I had to pass the comment's text to the partial. There's also a NoMethodError for :text in the partial thanks not making sense to me.

Comment: @ClydeBrown Include the `comment` variable in the form_for helper (`form_for [topic, post, comment]`).

Comment: Thanks for the comments addition, what was my problem here?

Comment: @ClydeBrown Take a look at the generated form URL. Without the comment, the URL would point to posts. Also make sure the `resources: comments` is nested under posts in routes.

Comment: How does the routes.rb above look?

Comment: @ClydeBrown You gotta decide on the URL format. If you want `/topics/1/posts/2/comments`, then you need `resources :topics { resources :posts { resources :comments }}` and `form_for(topic, post, comment)`. If you want `/posts/2/comments`, then you need to change the form_for to `form_for(post, comment)`.

Comment: Ahh ok, I just checkout out, makes sense. Thanks!